# How to vertically scroll elements of Constraint layout in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have `when(variable){ ConditionOne -> {ConstraintLayout{...}}` . There are Texts and OutlinedCards in ConstraintLayout. The screen is now filled and problem for scrolling vertically arises when i want to watch below items.
I tried `ConstraintLayout(modifier = modifier.scrollable(rememberScrollState(), orientation = Orientation.Vertical)){}` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you add a gif or video of your problem ? and please allow us to see the full composable function

Answer (score -1):

Jetpack Compose is a modern Android UI toolkit that allows you to build your user interfaces using a declarative syntax. While Compose is great for building dynamic and flexible UIs, it doesn't provide a ConstraintLayout in the same way as the XML-based layout system in traditional Android development. Instead, Compose has its own layout system and scrolling components. To vertically scroll elements in Compose, you can use the LazyColumn or VerticalScrollbar components. Here's how to do it:

```
@Composable    

fun ScrollableContentWithScrollbar() {    

val items = (1..100).toList() // Replace this with your data source.

val state = rememberScrollbarAdapter(
    scrollState = rememberLazyListState(),
    itemCount = items.size,
    averageItemSize = 50f // Adjust as needed
)

Box(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.verticalScrollbar(
            state = state
        ),
        state = state
    ) {
        items(items) { item ->
            // Your item content here
        }
    }
}
}
```